# (Answered) JSON file being entirely overwritten instead of just one line - Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

Edit: answered by @AlexChashin and @Martin down in the comments, thanks much

I'm creating a function that is suppose to receive a product name and a reference number as inputs. It then is suppose to read a json file of products and overwrite the reference number of the product it was sent. The issue is that it is overwriting the entire JSON file instead.

The JSON file looks like this to start:

```
{
    "ECMadrid": "tbd",
    "ECParis": "tbd2"
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
await jsonHelper.updateReferenceNumber("ECMadrid", "NewRef");
```

The function itself looks like this:

```
    async updateReferenceNumber(productName: string, newReference: string){
        let data = this.jsonReader('./filepath.json')
        data[productName] = newReference;
        fs.writeFile('./filepath.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), err => {
            console.log("I got here and the reference number is currently:", data[productName]);
            console.log("-------------------------------------------");
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error updating JSON:", err);
            }
        })
    }
```

```
    async jsonReader(filepath: string) {
        fs.promises.readFile(filepath, (err, fileData) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error reading JSON:", err);
            }
            try {
                const data = JSON.parse(fileData);
                console.log("Got to the jsonReader and I'm returning:", data);
                return data;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error parsing JSON:", err);
            }
        });
    }
```

After running it, my json file ends up like this:

```
{
  "ECMadrid": "NewRef"
}
```

And finally my console output from those console.log commands looks like this:

```
Got to after the writeFile and the reference number is currently: NewRef
-------------------------------------------
```

So one thing that's definitely worth noting as well is that the console.log command in my jsonReader function isn't firing.

I might have something wrong with promises or async stuff as those concepts are all pretty new to me, but I was expecting this to only overwrite the reference number of the product name I sent it, not the entire file. In the test file where these functions are being called, I'm also using another function that reads what the reference number of the product it is sent currently is and that is now working fine (thanks to people on this sight helping me), if you need to see that please let me know.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance, let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: JSON reading looks weird. You are using `fs.promises` which returns a promise that resolves when the file is read, but you are not `await`ing it, you are passing a callback? Maybe you meant `const fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(filepath)`, and then you also need to await the call to `jsonReader` like `const data = await this.jsonReader('./filepath.json')`

Comment: @AlexChashin tried what you suggested but now it's giving an error. It says "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ECMadrid')" pointing to the line `data[productName] = newReference;` in my updateReferenceNumber function

Comment: Did you `return data` from `jsonReader`?

Comment: yeah I did, I changed the line with the readFile command from what I had in my post to this: ```const fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(filepath, (err) => {```

Comment: You've still got an error callback... use try/catch

````try {
   const fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(filepath);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error:", err);
}````

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Working as intended now